# How can i get rid of getting "Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?" error while using BlueTooth service?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

**I got the following error:**

12-02 13:35:55.990 10977-10977/com.example.btpdemo76 E/ActivityThread: Activity com.zkc.pinter.activity.MainActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.zkc.helper.printer.BlueToothService$1@4179571 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
    android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.zkc.pinter.activity.MainActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.zkc.helper.printer.BlueToothService$1@4179571 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.(LoadedApk.java:1351)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1132)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1421)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1394)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1382)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:609)
        at com.zkc.helper.printer.BlueToothService.ScanDevice(BlueToothService.java:87)
        at com.zkc.helper.printer.bt.BtService$2.run(BtService.java:86)

**Here is my code**

public void scan() {

```
    if (!mBTService.IsOpen()) {
        mBTService.OpenDevice();
        return;
    }
    if (mBTService.getState() == STATE_SCANING)
        return;

    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            mBTService.ScanDevice();  
        }
    }.start();
}









public void ScanDevice() {
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    context.registerReceiver(mReceiver,  filter);  //showing error here

    filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
    context.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
    if (adapter.isDiscovering()) {
        adapter.cancelDiscovery();
    }
    setState(PrinterClass.STATE_SCANING);
    // Request discover from BluetoothAdapter
    adapter.startDiscovery();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you add a receiver dynamically, remember to unregister the same receiver in the `onPause()` method :

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
   unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
   super.onPause();
}
```

**Note:** do not place above codes in `onStop()` method because:

> this method may never be called, in low memory situations where the
>   system does not have enough memory to keep your activity's process
>   running after its onPause() method is called.